# "Execution Protection Violation" when running Jar in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, libgdx

I'm trying to export a game written in LibGDX, Java and Flixel-Android. The game was developed on a Mac, and runs on other Mac systems in Jar form. When running it on a Windows 7 machine it quits before completely starting up, and I get this dump:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x04a2b400, pid=5824,
>   tid=5912
>
> JRE version: 7.0_09-b05  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (23.5-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )  Problematic frame:  C 
>   0x04a2b400
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on
>   client versions of Windows
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.

The console window also prints "Execution protection violation" shortly before showing this, and then dumps the above into a text file as well. The text file includes a far, far longer dump that I won't post here unless people think necessary.

I have no idea what might be causing this, and I don't have much time to work it out! Anyone have any leads?

EDIT - I've narrowed it down to a section of code that loads a file from LibGDX's store. Is this a native library issue?

EDIT - It's somehow related to changing the size of a piece of text in Flixel-Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the native library doesn't work properly on windows and/or with Java 7 (I know, this is quite obvious).

Bear in mind that Android's java is is  java 1.5 compliant, so I could see that library breaking on java 7. I would verify which java versions are supported on the website of the library.

---

#### edit

It looks like java 7 is the culprit: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=824 .
I think I'm an expert google user...

Comment: Hmm. The link you post isn't exactly the same but I think you must be right - I've had others now tell me it's a Java 7 problem too. So any machine attempting to execut the jar using Java 7 won't run it? I'm completely buggered?

Comment: Unfortunately lots of applications don't run on java 7. At my job we're migrating to java 7, and it's not exactly as simple as it should be.

Comment: Good-oh. Thanks for your help! Off to bang my head against things.